# Beginners guide for Mesos, Marathon, Docker Integration

Tags: docker, akka-cluster, mesos, mesosphere, marathon

I am scratching my head, to figure out how the combination of docker, mess and marathon can help me in building my distributed application.

Application has a backend comprising of services processing client requests and returning json data, which is consumed by the fronted UI layer.Services need to be highly available and scalable. User interaction supported through REST and Web UI.

I would appreciate if some one can answer my following queries :

- Any example/ebook/guide for building an application using all of the above?
- Does mess/maraton offer built in support for clustering? or you need to use akka
  clustering or netty within containers?
- How load balancing works with mess/marathon?
- is my application a good use case for these technlogies?

Thanks

Comment: Mesosphere's [Docker on Mesos tutorial](http://mesosphere.com/docs/tutorials/launch-docker-container-on-mesosphere/) is a good place to start for specifically Docker. HAProxy is the suggested load balancer in [Marathon's load balancing](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/service-discovery-load-balancing.html) doc.